# Undefined residue at infinity

Tags: complex-analysis, residue-calculus

I am trying to find the residue of

$\frac{(cos(sin(z)))}{z^2}$ at $\infty$.

What I did was
$Res(f(x),\infty) = Res (f(\frac{1}{z}), z=0)$.

What I got was
$Res(z=0)=-z^2cos(sin(\frac{1}{z}))$ which is undefined.

What does it mean when the residue is undefined? Or was I not supposed to use this method for finding residues at infinity?

Comment: Welcome to MSE. For some basic information about writing mathematics at this site see, *e.g.*, [basic help on mathjax notation](/help/notation), [mathjax tutorial and quick reference](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5020), [main meta site math tutorial](//meta.stackexchange.com/a/70559) and [equation editing how-to](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1773).

Comment: The correct formula for the residue at $\infty$ is $\operatorname{Res}(f,\infty) = -\operatorname{Res}\left( {1\over z^2}f\left({1\over z}\right), 0  \right)$